# Error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, web-scraping

i have to simillar codes, one has multithreading and the other one doesnt. the one that has multithreading is getting this error **AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'** while the other isnt, here is my code:

multithreading:

```
import threading
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

symbolsfile = open("Stocklist.txt")

symbolslist = symbolsfile.read()

thesymbolslist = symbolslist.split("\n")

print (thesymbolslist)


print_lock = threading.Lock()

def th(ur):
    theurl = "http://money.cnn.com/quote/quote.html?symb=" + ur
    thepage = requests.get(theurl)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(thepage.content,"html.parser")
    textfind = soup.find('span',{"stream":"last_36276"})
    texttext = textfind.text
    with print_lock:
        print(textfind)

threadlist = []

for u in thesymbolslist:
    t = threading.Thread(target = th, args=(u,))
    t.start()

    threadlist.append(t)

for b in threadlist:
    b.join()
```

and the one without multithreading:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


theurl = "http://money.cnn.com/quote/quote.html?symb=" + "AAPL"
thepage = requests.get(theurl)
soup = BeautifulSoup(thepage.content,"html.parser")
textfind = soup.find('span',{"stream":"last_36276"})
texttext = textfind.text
print(texttext)
```

Comment: Do you need the thread? You should first make your working code use a method like the other code you've shown

Comment: what i am hoping for is to do the process form the working code with a bunch of other links. using multithreading would speed up my process. what i dont understand is why i am getting the error in the multithreading one

Comment: Yeah, `soup.find` should return something (that is the only `text` attribute I see)

Comment: the error seems to be in the textfind.text. altho in one program works fine, in the other one it doesnt. i cant seem to see how to fix it

Comment: Right, I'm saying that the soup.find seems to have returned None, which might happen if the BeautifulSoup text has not been loaded.

Comment: then it still has no explanation to why it would be returning none

Comment: You want  `textfind = soup.select_one('span[stream^=last_]')` as the digits change for each symbol

Comment: Did any of the comments or answers solve the problem?

Comment: nope, either that or i did not understand what they meant

Answer (score 0):

The multihreading code works perfectly fine on my system (Win10, Python 3.4-64bit) when `symbolslist` is set to `['AAPL']`. But the script crashes with the reported error when `symbolslist` is set to `['AAPL', 'IBM']`.

When inspecting the returned HTML code, you can see that once `stream="last_151846"` and once `stream="last_36276"` is used. When you change the `textfind` line to

```
textfind = soup.find('span',{"streamformat":"ToHundredth"})
```

or

```
textfind = soup.find('span',{"streamfeed":"SunGard"})
```

the code will work for those examples, and hopefully for the ones provided in `Stocklist.txt`.